# winfo_containing() always returning None?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

Consider the following code:

```
import Tkinter as tk # Python 2.7
screen = tk.Tk()
entry = tk.Entry(screen)
entry.place(x=0, y=0, width=100, height=20)
print(screen.winfo_containing(5, 5))
screen.mainloop()
```

Given the information under "winfo_containing" at http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm, I would expect this to print the identity of `entry`. E.g. something like "". Instead, I always get `None`. Why is this? The entry is a child to `screen`, and the co-ordinate (5, 5) falls within the location specified in my call to `place`.

Alternatively, is there a different way of getting the (top-most) widget at a certain location?

Comment: ``winfo_containing`` uses coordinates relative to the screen - your actual, physical screen, not a window that you happened to call 'screen'.  It's unlikely that global coordinate 5,5 falls within your window's initial location.  You may also need to call ``update_idletasks()`` (or actually enter the mainloop) before all geometry information is valid.

Answer (score 3):

What jasonharper says in his comment is right, `winfo_containing` takes coordinates relative to the actual computer screen, not the tkinter GUI, and you need to call `update_idletasks` before to get the right answer:

```
screen = tk.Tk()
entry = tk.Entry(screen)
entry.pack()
screen.update_idletasks()
x,y = screen.winfo_rootx(), screen.winfo_rooty()
print(screen.winfo_containing(x+5, y+5))
screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: This indeed no longer prints `None`! However, the call to `screen.winfo_containing` still returns the `Tk` instance (`screen`) rather than the `Entry` instance (`entry`).

Comment: When I execute the code on my computer, it returns the Entry instance (it does not depend on whether I use `entry.pack()` or `entry.place(x=0, y=0, width=100, height=20)`)